# ListView Thread on C#

Tags: c#, listview

Can anyone help me with this problem because I don't know how to handle it.

```
foreach (ListViewItem itemrow in this.listView1.Items)
{
     result = PumpStart.SymbolAdd(itemrow.SubItems[0].Text.Trim());
     if(result != ResultCode.Ok )
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Error adding symbol. " + mgr.ErrorDescription(result));
     }
}
```

But when I try to run the program, I have this error:

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is correctly Invalid operation, since a UI control can only be accessed and modified using Ui Thread, on any other thread this will lead to Invalid Operation Exception. Consider using BackgroundWorker or Async-Await

Comment: Looks like you are accessing the UI element from a different thread. Hope that `MethodInvoker` will help you to resolve this issue

Comment: can you give me an example on how to do it correctly?

Comment: Check the following article by Jon Skeet - http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If `listView1` is responsible for the Cross-thread error, then you will need to use it's `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` method to access and modify data.

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The Method executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's underlying handle was created on.

In other words: it pulls the piece of code that you want to execute back to the thread which created the `Control` that you want to modify.

`BeginInvoke` needs a `Delegate` as parameter. In this example [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) is serving this function:

```
this.listView1.BeginInvoke(
            new Action(() => 
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem itemrow in this.listView1.Items)
                {
                    result = PumpStart.SymbolAdd(itemrow.SubItems[0].Text.Trim());
                    if(result != ResultCode.Ok )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error adding symbol. " + mgr.ErrorDescription(result));
                    }
                }
            })
);
```